# Simple explanation/example for data- tags in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

Before you say there are tons of sources explaining it, I am telling you that I spent time researching it and still wonder about stuff :)

So, Im new to web developing and the past couple of months I built strong skills in integrating `HTML/CSS/JS` and some `PHP`. However I wrote all my markup, selectors,etc with the old school "class" and "id" tags. Now that I see the more modernized style I see alot of webpages using the data-tag. Now the question is, can these tags be related to `"class"` and `"id"` in any way?If it does, What is really the core advantage of it? I need simple examples to understand this concept. Yes I know its a custom data attribute and so on, But what makes it more useful than other tags?

Would highly appreciate simple examples and explanations :)

Comment: Ah, seriously? `:/` What did you understand and what you didn't?

Comment: You use it to store custom data. Lets say you want to save a youtube ID for and on click event. You just put it in that data tag of a button.

Comment: In jQuery  they are used to store information on tags that for example would be in a value attribute on an input tag or to store information on the relevant tag instead of cookies. in Angular, it is used for directives. There are different reasons for the data attribute in different frameworks so the answer is "it depends"

Comment: data- attributes are not related to class or id, class or id are for CSS, jQuery, data-attributes are custom extra info that can be used by CSS or jQuery

Comment: In addition to @HoschNok , it's for data that does not belong in other attributes. For example: you wouldn't store that youtube ID in the class attribute. One would usually access this data with javascript.

Comment: I'm new to HTML5 tags sooo yea. Um, as an example, there is a feature in the JS plugin appear.js called appearlazy, in order to integrate its features (Which I was not able to do since it used data tags) you have to include "data-src" and include the JS files. Now why? Why did they use the data- tag? Why did they not create a class or id like bootstrap? Right now there is a huggge cloud of confusion in my head regarding the data tag haha.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and IDs have different uses/purposes than `data-*` attributes, I think.

For example, a class helps describe a **hierarchy**. Members of certain classes get certain states and styles (from CSS) or different behaviors (from JavaScript, for example). An ID is similar, but it's unique to one component. So while it is helpful sometimes in describing the state or the style of an element, it's also very useful in targeting a specific element in JavaScript.

`data-*` attributes have a whole slew of purposes. But their primary purpose for being is what their name implies: to hold data, or information, about an element. Elements don't have many other ways to do that.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

> for data that should be associated with a particular element but need
>   not have any defined meaning

For example, pretend you're building a calculator application. You have a **display**, a **keypad**, and **keys**.

Each **key** could have the class `.key`, which helps describe its state/style. Each key could have an ID as well (e.g. `#divide`), but how do you further sub-divide those keys to describe them?

Well, the number keys could have `data-type="operand"`, and the plus, minus, subtract keys, etc., could have `data-type="operator"`. You could argue that you might not use the classes `.operand` and `.operator`, because being an operand or an operator is not a mutable state of those keys... Instead, it is a distinguishable **property** that does not further help describe the key's state like a class would. Why use `data-type`? Well, as MDN says, we use that in place of a made-up attribute, since a `div.key` doesn't have a native HTML `type` attribute.

Why is this useful? Well, in your JavaScript, you can target those keys by doing, for example, `$([data-type="operand"]).on('click', doSomething)`. This accurately describes the element, and why you are selecting the element. The exact same thing is possible if you were to have used a class or even an ID, but I think in this case, the `data-*` attribute helps to **abstract the properties away from the states and behaviors**.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using `data` attributes in HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function showDetails(animal) {
      var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
      alert("The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Species</h1>
  <p>Click on a species to see what type it is:</p>

  <ul>
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you not attach the events using the class attribute? This is where im confused, how is it really really different?

Comment: Yes, you can use any technique to attach events. This example shows how you can specify values for data attributes and how you can read it. You can use pure javascript, or jQuery or Angular (etc) selectors to read the data attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some reading on data-attributes...

class and id are attributes used to identify an element,

data-* is a personalized tag the programmer can use to store information to use those in the code.

This is about code organization, you use data-* when there is no specific attribute for your information about the tag.